# Cannot create javascript object from extended file via require

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have a problem with the creation of an object from an external javascript file.

This is my UsersCollection.js content:

```
var self;

var UsersCollection = function() {
    this.users = [];
    self = this;
};

UsersCollection.prototype.add = function(user) {
    self.users.push(user);
};
```

And this is my node.js server file fragment

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;

var rooms = [];
var games = [];

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

require('./logic/UsersCollection.js');
var usersCollection = new UsersCollection();
```

When I'm running a server I have error:

```
var usersCollection = new UsersCollection();
                          ^
ReferenceError: UsersCollection is not defined
```

What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Thanks guys, it's working :)
I added

```
module.exports = UsersCollection;
```

to UsersCollection.js and

```
var UsersCollection = require('./logic/UsersCollection.js');
var usersCollection = new UsersCollection();
```

to server.js

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and post your solution as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't assign your required file to a variable:

```
var UsersCollection = require('./logic/UsersCollection.js');
var usersCollection = new UsersCollection();
```

Moreover in the `UsersCollection.js` you need to export the `UsersCollection`

```
module.exports = UsersCollection;
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt see the export from your UsersCollection.js file like :

```
module.export = UsersCollection
```

If you add this line in your UserCollection.js file then you will be able to require it from another one file.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your require file should look like this if you are  accessing **UsersCollection.js** file which inside logic folder which is in parent directory of your current file

```
require('../logic/UsersCollection.js');
```